# Opposing alignment of multiple lines of long text without exceeding \linewidth

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I'm trying to create some documents using the [flashcards](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/flashcards/) macros, and I'd like to have the text aligned like follows

```
    ____________________________________
   |                                    |
   | A string      An Xtra long string  |
   | B string                 C string  |
   | An Xtra long string 2    D string  |
   |                                    |
    ------------------------------------
```

I tried using the `tabular*` environment, which seems quite suitable, used as follows:

```
\begin{tabular*}
A string               & An Xtra long string \\
B string               & C string \\
An Xtra long string 2  & D string
\end{tabular*}
```

Unfortunately the result overflows horizontally, something like this:

```
    ____________________________________
   |                                    |
   | A string               An Xtra long string
   | B string                          C string
   | An Xtra long string 2             D string
   |                                    |
    ------------------------------------
```

So I've tried using `makebox`, like this:

```
\makebox[.48\linewidth][l]{A string} 
\makebox[.48\linewidth][r]{An Xtra long string} \\
\makebox[.48\linewidth][l]{B string} 
\makebox[.48\linewidth][r]{C string} \\    
\makebox[.48\linewidth][l]{An Xtra long string 2} 
\makebox[.48\linewidth][r]{D string}
```

But this results in too much vertical padding, something like this:

```
     ____________________________________
    |                                    |
    | A string      An Xtra long string  |
    |                                    |
    | B string                 C string  |
    |                                    |
    | An Xtra long string 2    D string  |
     ------------------------------------
```

Which is also not the desired result.

I think (hope) I've clearly demonstrated the outcome I desire. So far I've been  mucking about, but I suspect there's a relatively easy way to accomplish this.

I would be grateful for any feedback or suggestions that you think may be of assistance.

Comment: Note that you don't have to (and shouldn't) sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one option... use \hfill.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\parbox{2in}{%
A string \hfill An Xtra long string \\
B string \hfill C string \\
An Xtra long string 2 \hfill  D string
}
\end{document}
```

(You don't really need the parbox; it's just that the point is easiest to see with a narrower width.)

[image]

I have another option which I'll post separately so it can be voted on separately or accepted/unaccepted separately.

Comment: This works, but I have to add `\vspace*{-0.9ex}` to the end of all the lines. Thanks!

Comment: Another great option in the `memoir` class is `\leftspringright{⟨lfrac⟩}{⟨rfrac⟩}{⟨ltext⟩}{⟨rtext⟩}`, though it requires some tinkering to make it work. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a tabbing environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\parbox{2in}{%
\begin{tabbing}
A string \` An Xtra long string \\
B string \` C string \\
An Xtra long string 2 \` D string
\end{tabbing}
}
\end{document}
```

I was going to post another screenshot, but I can't tell the difference between this output and the one I posted earlier, so...